# Django save_m2m() and excluded field

Tags: django, forms, model, save

*UPDATE: I ended up creating a new forms.Form instead of using a ModelForm*

In a ModelForm, I replaced a field by excluding it and adding a new one
with the same name, as shown below in AddRestaurantForm. When saving
the form with the code shown below, I get an error in form.save_m2m()
("Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value"), which seems to be due to the
function to attempt to save the tag field, while it is excluded.

Is the save_m2m() function supposed to save excluded fields?
Is there anything wrong in my code?

Thanks
Jul

```
(...)
new_restaurant = form.save(commit=False)
new_restaurant.city = city
new_restaurant.save()

tags =  form.cleaned_data['tag']
if(tags!=''): tags=tags.split(',')
for t in tags:
    tag, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name = t.strip())
    tag.save()
    new_restaurant.tag.add(tag)

new_restaurant.save()
form.save_m2m()
```

***models.py***

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

class Restaurant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city=models.ForeignKey(City)
    category=models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    tag=models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, null=True)
```

***forms.py***

```
class AddRestaurantForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=classtext))
    city = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=classtext), max_length=100)
    tag = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=classtext), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Restaurant
        exclude = ('city','tag')
```

Traceback:

> File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/core/handlers/base.py" 
>   in get_response
>     92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args,
>   **callback_kwargs)   File "/home/jul/atable/../atable/resto/views.py" in addRestaurant
>     498.                 form.save_m2m()   File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/forms/models.py" in
>   save_m2m
>     75.                 f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])   File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/db/models/fields/
>   related.py" in save_form_data
>     967.         setattr(instance, self.attname, data)   File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/db/models/fields/
>   related.py" in **set**
>     627.         manager.add(*value)   File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/db/models/fields/
>   related.py" in add
>     430.                 self._add_items(self.source_col_name,   self.target_col_name, *objs)   File
>   "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/db/models/fields/
>   related.py" in _add_items
>     497.                     [self._pk_val] + list(new_ids))   File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/db/backends/util.py" in
>   execute
>     19.             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/django/db/backends/mysql/
>   base.py" in execute
>     84.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)   File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
>     168.         if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()   File "/var/lib/python-support/python2.5/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in
>   _warning_check
>     82.                     warn(w[-1], self.Warning, 3)   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/warnings.py" in warn
>     62.                   globals)   File "/usr/lib/python2.5/warnings.py" in warn_explicit
>     102.         raise message
>
> Exception Type: Warning at /restaurant/add/   Exception Value:
>   Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'a'

Comment: You define `name` in the form but you do not exclude it, and it is defined in the restaurant model. I would have though you don't need to define it again in the Form.

Comment: Yes, I do that to add attributes to the widget.

Answer (score 0):

I see you also posted this same question to Django-users. I'll copy the answer I've posted there:

Firstly, it is no use just giving the name of the error. Errors come 
with tracebacks, for good reason: they allow us to see exactly where 
the error is occurring, and the context.

Anyway, in your case, there doesn't seem to be any need to use 
`save_m2m`. The documentation states:

> "Calling save_m2m() is only required if you use save(commit=False)"

In your case, you've already saved the form to get the `new_restaurant` 
instance, and you're adding tags to that instance with no problem. The 
last two calls, to `new_restaurant.save()` and `form.save_m2m()`, are unnecessary.

Comment: I actually need the form.save_m2m() because I've got another m2m field in my Restaurant model (I updated the code). I've added the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need either of the last two "save" calls. Your tags relation will be implicitly saved by virtue of the add(). I'd just drop those from the code.

Comment: I actually need the form.save_m2m() because I've got another m2m field in my Restaurant model (I updated the code).